# Using HTML5 multiple file upload with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, file-upload, file-io

I'm trying to upload multiple files using

`<input id="testUpload" type="file" multiple="true"/>`

(yes, i know it doesn't work on IE). But my question is what should i do after that in the code to iterate through each file and upload it ?

I'm trying

```
foreach(HttpPostedFile file in Request.Files["testUpload"]){

}
```

But i get

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' because 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

I know i can just do for `multiple = "false"` :

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["testUpload"];
```

And then do operation on that file. But what if i'm selecting multiple files ? How to iterate though each one using `foreach` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over one file rather than the collection.

Change

```
foreach(HttpPostedFile file in Request.Files["testUpload"]){

}
```

to

**EDIT** - changed to for loop as per comment

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
    if(file .ContentLength >0){
    //saving code here

  }
```

Comment: Hmm, i get this error in the `foreach` line :
`Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase'.`

Comment: After the edit it works. But when i upload the files i only get one file uploaded ! and i try to output what's uploaded and get this for 3 different files one of them is `Koala.jpg` :
`Koala.jpg Uploaded! 
Koala.jpg Uploaded! 
Koala.jpg Uploaded! `

Comment: That tells me 3 files are being picked. Where are you outputting the values? I've got  sample running on my machine and the code works as expected in Chrome. Also look at the Request.Files object in the debugger to see what is contained within it. This may give you some pointers as to where you're code is failing

Comment: I'v tried to debug it. Found that `AllKeys` property contains 3 files named after the `input` tag id which is `testUpload` ! Why is that happening ?!

Comment: See my new edit. This is because one input control is posting into the Files collection.  By iterating over the collection by **index** you can get the individual HttpPostedFileBase then.

Comment: Yea, the new edit works. But i really don't understand why `foreach` produces such an input ? Can you elaborate your last comment more ? Thanks.

Comment: The foreach was iterating over the collection by name. In this case even though there is three items in the file collection the name of each File item is testUpload because all three files were posted from the same input element called testUpload. If you had three differently named input elements the foreach loop would have worked because the File name value would have been different

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Thank you, Thank you. It saved my day.

However, I had to use HttpPostedFile instead of HttpPostedFileBase.

```js
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    **HttpPostedFile** file = Request.Files[i];
    if(file .ContentLength >0){
    //saving code here
    }
}
```

Either way, this is great